# Openlayers -- Is there a way to delay server requests on zoom for a particular layer?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a rather complex issue where I have 10 TMS Layers (I'm using OpenLayers) that animate. When I zoom in and out quickly I can quickly rack up 1000's of hits to the same server. Is there a way I can delay the request of that layer until zooming has stopped for x amount of time?

Thanks!

Comment: have some code that shows how you are loading the data right now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation control has option to send less tile requests to the server when wheel-zooming.
See example:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mousewheel-interval.html