# Prevent sending too many requests while zooming/paning (OpenLayers 6.15)

Tags: openlayers, tiles, performance, zoom

I have a web page that displays WMS data from a WMS server, using a `TileLayer`. The images are fetched with a callback function called by the `setTileLoadFunction(..)` method of the associated `TileWMS` source object.

Every time I zoom on several levels using several scrolls from the mouse, or when I pan through great distances using several drag movements, there are too many requests that are sent between the beginning and the end of the whole scroll/pan that won't be used anyway and that overload the WMS servers, preventing it to quickly send the responses from the last requests.

Is there a practical way to set a kind of timeOut/debounce to prevent requests to be sent between two quick and consecutive pans/scrolls?

What I tried:

- To follow the `moveend` events: it seems independent from the setTileLoadFunction() call from the TileWMS instance that triggers the sending of requests, couldn't find a way to prevent/delay the sending of requests from here.
- To put the callback of `setTileLoadFunction()` within a lodash/debounce method (like `source.setTileLoadFunction(_.debounce(myCallback, 500))`: the results are erratic, the fact that I'm requesting tiles isn't helping, and performance are much worst with this.

Comment: I don't know if this is related or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413226/delay-of-wms-request-after-mousewheelzoom. Or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_MouseWheelZoom-MouseWheelZoom.html

Comment: @user30184 The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413226/delay-of-wms-request-after-mousewheelzoom seems related, as the issue seems to be the same, even if the answer doesn't provide much of a solution.
I could find some other related questions like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150030/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-tile-processing-from-openlayers-3-when-user-pan-zoom or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43828/openlayers-is-there-a-way-to-delay-server-requests-on-zoom-for-a-particular-l but the answers aren't answering the question I ask.

Comment: @Kadjoe old answers are unlikely to be relevant to version 6 or later, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#always-load-tiles-while-animating-or-interacting

Answer (score 0):

Before the `tileLoadFunction` is called the tile is queued - if you do not load the tile it will not be available if needed later and the queue will become full.

You could use larger tiles as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-custom-tilegrid-512x256.html to reduce the number of requests.  512 x 512 tiles need only a quarter of the requests needed for the default 256 x 256 tiles.

You could also try increasing the interval between resolutions at which tiles are requested, for example

```
const startResolution = getWidth(projExtent) / 512;
const resolutions = new Array(11);
for (let i = 0, ii = resolutions.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  resolutions[i] = startResolution / Math.pow(2, i * 2);
}
```